# Chrome Extension form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome-extension

what I want to do, is to create call a function which can create a form and submit it every time a specific page is called.e.g

```
function foo(url){
  var form = document.createElement("form");
  var input1 = document.createElement("input");
  var input2 = document.createElement("input");

  form.method = "POST";
  form.action = url;
  form.name = "myForm";
  form.id = "form_id";

  input1.type = "hidden";
  input1.value = "value";
  input1.blahblah...

  input2.type = "hidden";
  input2.value = "value";
  input2.blahblah...

  form.appendChild(input1);
  form.appendChild(input2);
  document.body.appendChild(form);

  form.submit();

  alert("Form submitted");
}
```

The thing is that, even since the form is appended in the document, the submit is not working for some reason. (alert never comes up);

Any ideas where the problem is?

(or any alternative to do this)

Thanks

Comment: Ajax is the way to post data to a script without the need of a form (or page even)

Comment: Any errors in the console? the alert should be before the `submit()`

Comment: Submit redirects your page (effectively killing your extension, since its background page ceases to run). Alex K. is correct.

Comment: what if I have to do this with a form.. :/ this is what gets me confused...

Answer (score 0):

```html
function foo(url)
{
  var form1 = document.createElement("form");
  var input1 = document.createElement("input");
  var input2 = document.createElement("input");

  form1.method = "POST";
  form1.action = url;
  form1.name = "myForm";
  form1.id = "form_id";

  input1.type = "hidden";
  input1.value = "value";

  input2.type = "hidden";
  input2.value = "value";

  form1.appendChild(input1);
  form1.appendChild(input2);
  document.body.appendChild(form1);

  form1.submit();

  alert("Form submitted");
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? please provide some context to the code in your answer.